# Please explain this structures function in C

Tags: c, modulus

This is the solution to a problem for a course I'm doing. The assignment asks to create a function that returns a structure containing the following calendar date passed through. I'm completely lost on how this code works. Can someone please break it down step-by-step after the array is declared?

I especially don't understand the syntax `x.year==400`. Doesn't the formula require a `%400` to determine whether the year's a leap year?

I also have no idea what `if(x.day >array[x.month-1])` means. Is this the same "array" declared within this function? If so, I thought it contains the values "31, 28....etc" and not the structure date and its component "month". I really don't understand much of it at all so any feedback is welcome.

```
struct date advanceDay(struct date x)
{ // 'x' = whatever instance of 'struct date' is passed to function
    int array[]= {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}; //number of days in each calendar month
    if ((x.year%4 == 0 && x.year%100 != 0) || x.year==400) array [1] = 29; //Leap year formula on previous commentary
    x.day++;

    if (x.day > array[x.month-1]) {
        x.month++;
        x.day = 1;
    }
    if (x.month > 12) {
        x.year++;
        x.month = 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the code has flaw. "x.year==400"  should be " 0 == x.year%400".

Comment: If we check January, then x.month =1 , we need to check array[0]. So "array[x.month-1]" is right.

Answer (score 1):

Your function adds one day to x. Let us take an example
Let `x = {31,01,2020}` which is the 31th of January 2020.

- The first `if` statement is checking if the `x.year` is a leap year, if it is leap then change the number of the days to 29 in `array[1]` which corresponds to the month of February.
- `x.day++;` increments `x.day` by one so `x.day=32` now.
  Here `array[x.month-1]=array[1-1]=array[0]=31`.
  The second `if` statement is checking if the incremented `x.day` is still a day of `x.month`, here `x.day = 32` which is greater than the number of days of January. So the program increment `x.month` and set `x.day` to one. Now we have `x.day=01` and `x.month=02` (February).
- the last `if` statement checks if `x.month` is greater than 12 which is the maximum number of months for one year. If it is superior then set the `x.month` to 1 (January) and increment `x.month` by one. Our `x.month=02` so it doesn't fulfil the condition of the `if` statement.
- Finally it returns `x={01,02,2020}` which is correctly the day next to `x={31,01,2020}`.